# Execute Package.Error is:The variable cannot be found

Tags: ssis

I am facing below error while SSIS execution:

> Execute Package.Error is:The variable cannot be found. This occurs
>   when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables
>   collection on a container during execution of the package, and the
>   variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the
>   variable is not being created.

Points to consider are as below:

1. We have around 1,00,000 text files in folder for Import in SSIS
   package(we import text file in SQL Temp table)
2. We are executing SSIS import in 2 Thread using Parallel.For loop.
3. After execution of 65,000 around file Package start giving above error.
4. After this error, it not able to import any of Remaing files and throwing the same error.

I am only using one variable in my package as below,

```
    importInventoryPackage.Connections["DestinationConnectionOLEDB"].ConnectionString = Shared.ConnectionStringToExecutePackage;
    importInventoryPackage.Connections["SourceConnectionFlatFile"].ConnectionString = inventoryFilePath;
    importInventoryPackage.Variables["tempTableName"].Value = tempTableName;
```

I searched on google for similar kind of issue but not found any fix.
We again tried assign vraiable when this error throw but still it gives same error while Importing remianing files..

Can any one help in resolving this issue ..how can i resolve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that this is related to the same variable being written to in multiple components that execute in parallel. Essentially this would be a race condition on that variable.

For example if Component A and Component B can execute in parallel and both write to a given variable then it is possible that Component A will be writing to it (rendering it unavailable) when Component B tries to execute. As the start time of the two jobs will vary between runs you can get cases where the package appears to fail randomly.

To resolve the issue you would need to either add an additional variable so that they are not shared or alternatively force one component to complete before the other begins (through a dependency).

Hope this helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883372/7462678

Comment: I am planning to execute SSIS import using multiple Thread, how can i created individual variable per Thread and assign to Package variable ? i am using single function in Thread, i also tried with lock condition but still no solution...

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779767/ssis-intermittent-variable-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified